# KML using html-code for characters

Tags: kml

I now that you can use & lt; etc... in KML. But I use also & iacute; = í, & eacute; = é or & uuml; = ü etc...(without the space behind &) But Google Earth do not accept that in a tag

<name>Potos& iacute;</name> is not accept by Google Earth.

I need that CHAR-codes for text on my site and the same text is used in the KML export.

Answer (score 1):

If want HTML entities to correctly decode in Google Earth then wrap the text with entities with CDATA block which is then treated as HTML vs plain text.

This will add an special entity to the placemark name.

```
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
 <Placemark>          
   <name><![CDATA[abc&iacute;]]></name>
   ...
 </Placemark>          
</kml>
```

Also, if the HTML entity does not decode then simply replace that with the
equivalent numerical code; e.g. `&iacute;` = `&#x000ED;` = `&#237;`. Check [KML Errata](http://kml4earth.appspot.com/kmlErrata.html#encoding) for a short discussion of HTML entity encoding in KML.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved. I have the code `&iacute;` replaced by `&#237;`